# Nightly batch network task on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, background, heroku

We're working on a Rails project on Heroku that needs to scrape and process data each night for each user.  This requires many Internet accesses per user, and we're hoping to be able to support tens of thousands of users.  While there's a fair bit of parsing, calculating, and writing to databases involved, we expect that most of the task's time will be spent waiting on data from the network.

What's the best general approach to doing this task while minimizing both wallclock time and Heroku fees?  Obviously either concurrency or async networking will be needed to take advantage of the time spent waiting for the network, but how should we go about it?  We're thinking in terms of a database-backed queue with forked worker processes, but that may not be the best approach—or may not even be possible on Heroku.

Comment: You don't mention if the amount of scraping/parsing scales with the amount of users on the system...

Comment: It does—each of our users corresponds to another set of pages that need to be scraped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroku [supports Delayed Job](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job), I would start there. You can then do the following:

- create a job class that does the processing for a single user
- schedule a [nightly cron](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) that creates a job for every user in your system
- auto-scale your workers to accommodate the job queue ([workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) or similar should be able to do this for you. If not, you may have to roll some custom code.)

You'll need to play with your workers/jobs ratio to figure out the sweet spot for optimizing across db load, wallclock time and heroku costs.

If you're finding that each job spends too much time sitting around waiting for network, take a look at [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine). Jobs are just ruby code, so you can play whatever parallelization tricks you want here, Heroku shouldn't limit you in any way.

This setup would be a pretty good baseline to get to as it shouldn't take very long to spin up and you'll probably learn a bit about your work load from it.

You might find out that 1 job/user doesn't make sense, and that you need n jobs per user (one job per property or something). Without knowing your exact usecase it's hard to say up front, that's why I'm assuming a 1-1 mapping.

I should also point out that the new Heroku stack [supports queueing systems other than Delayed Job](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queueing) (scroll to bottom).

Answer (score 2):

Delayed Job is great, I recommend it heartily. Add the HireFire gem to make it even better -- this gem automatically increases the number of worker processes when a backlog of jobs is accumulating, and shuts the workers down when there are no jobs to do. If you use HireFire, though, don't schedule jobs to run in the future -- just queue them up when you want them to run, perhaps inside a rake task run by Heroku's Cron addon. (HireFire won't start up the worker processes correctly if you try to schedule jobs for the future.)

You can configure the maximum number of workers which HireFire will use, and how it adds workers as the backlog of jobs grows. This makes it very easy to scale. You will need to choose an appropriate "grain size" for your scraping/parsing jobs (how many 100s or 1000s of users should be processed in a single job). Then inside your Cron task, divide all the users into groups of the appropriate size, queue up a background job for each group, and let HireFire start an appropriate number of worker processes to finish all the jobs promptly.

This still leaves the problem of minimizing dyno-hour costs. I recently dealt with the same problem on a Rails site I was building...

The site pulls data from various web services using `delayed_job` background workers. I got a performance increase of close to 10x for that data pull job, by running multiple HTTP requests in parallel, using a parallel map-reduce utility which I built myself.

I intend to do some more work on that map-reduce implementation, but if you want to use it now you are welcome to it: https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-threads/threads.rb

The higher your ratio of wait time/processing time is, the more you stand to gain. Let me know if you would like a sample of the background job code which uses that utility.